# How to fix clang libc++ error on Mac: calling private constructor

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, clang++, libc++

I'm trying to compile a (private) C++ software with Clang and libc++ on Mac OS X 10.10 and am getting this error:

```
error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<unsigned short *>'
```

Full error message [here](https://gist.github.com/cdeil/5d5b1bec5fb0bb0a3e58#file-gistfile1-txt-L29).

Can someone explain this error and how to fix it?
A small self-contained code example that results in this error and an option how to re-write it so that it works would be great!

Comment: The compiler is obviously telling you to make the code `public` as it can't access it `;-)`. Unhelpful little pun, I know. Are you sure you aren't doing something illegal (as in, copying an uncopyable class) when calling `UShortVector::iterator(entry.iter)`? It seems that inherits from some `std` iterator class that prohibits the operation you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for a self-contained example showing the error but haven't provided your own example?  That's not how stackoverflow works, you are meant to show the code not make people guess at the problem!

This produces the error:

```
#include <vector>

void f(unsigned short* p)
{
    std::vector<unsigned short>::iterator i(p);
}
```

Looks as though you're trying to construct an iterator from a pointer, which is not valid (it might work with some compilers, but is not portable).

You could try using pointer arithmetic to get the iterator instead:

```
std::ptrdiff_t d = std::distance(vec.data(), p);
std::vector<unsigned short>::iterator i = vec.begin() + d;
```

This assumes `p` really does point to an element of the vector, otherwise `distance(vec.data(), p)` is undefined.

Comment: Apologies for not posting a self-contained example myself ... it's a non-public large, old, complex codebase and I'm not a C++ expert.
Thanks for your help ... I'll try it out!

Comment: Do you have an authoritative reference (say a page in the standard) that constructing a pointer from an iterator is not legal ISO C++?

I've tried your code example with all compilers (different Clang and GCC versions and some others) here: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ ... they all don't complain!

At http://melpon.org/wandbox/ the example works with all GCC versions and -std flags, but gives the error I see on Mac with all Clang versions and flags.

If this is not standard C++ it should be possible to get a warning / error on any computer with a recent GCC and Clang and the right -std flag, no?

Comment: In [vector.overview]/2 the standard says `std::vector::iterator` is an implementation-defined type, so beyond the required RandomAccessIterator semantics any other behaviour (such as constructing from raw pointers) varies from implementation to implementation. Clang on gcc.godbolt.org uses GCC's standard library, so it's unsurprising you get the same results as with GCC.