# error when inserting a char via string::insert

Tags: c++, string

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906589/how-to-fix-clang-libc-error-on-mac-calling-private-constructor) but there is no sample code there, and I didn't find it helpful.

My error is

> calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter'

A minimal example of my problem can be found below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string g = "this_word";
    cout << g << endl;
    char temp = g[0];
    g.erase(0,1);
    cout << g << endl;
    g.insert(0,temp); // Compiler seems to dislike this.  Why?
    cout << g << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried this through two compilers, and the same error.  Read as much as I could from the standard documentation, but don't understand my error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to check all the signatures of overloads of [std::string::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) then decide to use which one. `g.insert(0,temp);` just doesn't match any of them.

For inserting a `char`, you can pass an iterator like

```
g.insert(g.begin(), temp);
```

or pass the index and count together:

```
g.insert(0, 1, temp);
```

Comment: There's also an overload that takes an index, count and `char` so `g.insert(0, 1, temp);` would work.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Good idea, added to the answer.

Comment: Very helpful.  I'll note, I ended up passing in a string, which did the trick.     g.insert(0,charToString(savedLetter));